# Can't declare javaExceptionMapper in Application Config file

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm working JAX-RS, and I have made two custom ExceptionMapper, to JSOn error codes, in case of an error:

```
package Exception;

import Facade.ErrorMessage;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
//dette fungere ligesom et hierki, så først, kommer de laveste i hierkiet, og denne bliver kaldt, hvis der ikke er andre exceptions, der er fundet inden
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {



    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(exception.getMessage(),
                500,
                "This message has been displayed, because the data was inavalid, please use another parameter as data");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).build();
    }
    }
```

In my applicationCofing, I get the error `cannot find symbol`
for both of my exception mappers.

```
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(Exception.DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.class); // cannot find symbol for DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.class
    resources.add(Exception.GenericExceptionMapper.class); // cannot find symbol
    resources.add(Rest.AddressResource.class);
    resources.add(Rest.CityinfoResource.class);
    resources.add(Rest.HobbyResource.class);
    resources.add(Rest.PersonResource.class);
    resources.add(Rest.PhoneResource.class);
}
}
```

should I not declare them in my rest config, or how can I resolve this?

EDIT: when i moved my mappers from my exception package, to my Rest package, the problem stopped, but i want to have them in a seperate folders, for better structure.

Comment: Use java naming convention dude;  packages begin with lower case letters. I wonder if there is a conflict with your package name and the global Exception class.

Comment: yeah that was it... Thank you so much